# How to use "if you will"

Tags: punctuation

What is the proper way to use *if you will*?
Here is an example.

> It's like riding a car, if you will.

Is the punctuation right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that punctuation is correct.

**If you will** can be considered short for "if you will allow this analogy", which is the usage in your car example.

> I once rode on the back of a camel. It's like riding a car, *if you will permit the analogy*.

As Elendil says it can also mean "if you want to".

> Imagine, *if you like*, a typical silversmith's shop.

Comment: Haven't seen the longer version `if you will allow this analogy` used - is it common in writing or speech?

Comment: That longer phrase is not standard, I just wrote that to explain the meaning of `if you will`. But `if you will` is certainly used in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that seems good to me. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has this example: “imagine, if you will, a typical silversmith's shop”.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to "Imagine, please..."?  That's a common usage, but not OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

The punctuation is correct in your example but the usage is perhaps a little off.

'If you will' is short for 'if you will it', or 'if you want to'.

Therefore FX_'s example is saying:

> 'Imagine, if you want to, a typical silversmith's shop.

It can also be read as asking the reader to make a concession to what you are saying:

> 'The man was Australian, from 'Down Under', if you will.

Here you are 'asking' the reader to accept the use of 'Down Under'.

Comment: @Elendil "if you want to" is not the only interpretation of this. The car example does make sense, but doesn't have quite the meaning you indicate.

Comment: I stand corrected, and edit to that effect. :)